# How to merge two dataframes having only one parameter common in both?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I have two data frames. I want to merge 2nd data frame into the first one based on the state name. I also want to create additional columns and then calculate the percentage change of population for the year  2010 to 2016  and death for the same duration. I want to see the behavior of death cases in comparison to the population.

```
df1 = {'GoArea':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Census2010':[100000,150000,110000],'2010_popln':[110000,150500,110070] ,
     '2010_popln':[110000,150500,110070] , '2011_popln':[115000,151500,118070] ,'2012_popln': [135000,168500,120070], 
      '2013_popln' :[138000,178500,200070] }  

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)

df2 = { 'Year':['2010','2011','2012','2013','2010','2011','2012','2013','2010','2011','2012','2013'] , 
       'State' :['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'] , 'Death' :[23,45,67,8,34,54,56,78,32,67,89,10]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

So I want to add only new columns like DeathYear2010,DY2011, DY2012,DY2013
and then map the values based on  state  , GeoArea and year in the dataframe 1 so that I can use this new dataframe for other calculations

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example as code (not image!)

Comment: I have added the steps for dataframe and the output which I want